# bunyan log.child correct use case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, express, bunyan

I've been looking at `bunyan` for logging in my nodejs app. I tried it out and everything seems to work pretty well. I had skipped over [a section](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#logchild) on `log.child`, but now I'm trying to understand how to use it. I think it's purpose is to allow me to specify some special identifier to the log entry, so that I can uniquely identify how that log is associated to some other log entry.

If that's the case, I would envision myself using `log.child` in every request:

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var log = bunyan.createLogger({name: 'myapp'});

router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    var logChild = log.child({reqId: uuid.v4()});
    logChild.info({ req:req }, req.user.name + ' has called /submit');

    saveData(req)
    .then(function(data) {
        logChild.info({data: data}, req.user.name + ' has saved to DB successfully in /submit');
        res.json({'success': 'Saved!'});
    })
    .error(function(err) {
        logChild.error({ err: err }, req.user.name + ' has caused an error in /submit ');
        res.status(500).json("error": err});
    }); 
});
```

That way, if a user `Bob` POSTs to `/submit` twice in a 30 sec span,  there will be some context that differentiates between two different calls in the log file.

That is, I'll see something like this (with context):

```
Bob has called /submit uuid: 109156be-c4fb-41ea-b1b4-efe1671c5836
Bob has called /submit uuid: 49dlsd7i-dapd-fdio-fei0-sd59fd0ph34d
Bob has saved to DB successfully in /submit uuid: 109156be-c4fb-41ea-b1b4-efe1671c5836
Bob has caused an error in /submit uuid: 49dlsd7i-dapd-fdio-fei0-sd59fd0ph34d
```

Instead of this (no context):

```
Bob has called /submit
Bob has called /submit
Bob has saved to DB successfully in /submit
Bob has caused an error in /submit
```

And so for all my routes in my Nodejs app, I would create the `logChild` object, then use the `logChild` to log the entries in that route.

Am I **understanding** and **implementing** the use case of `log.child` correctly?

Answer (score 14):

You seem to be using log.child appropriately. One suggestion I could make to assist you in "uniquely identifying how that log is associated to some other log entry" is by attaching `log` to the `req` object. This way, if you have different middleware, you can access the same logger with the same unique id from multiple places. For example:

```
var log = bunyan.createLogger({name: 'myapp'});

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.log = log.child({ user : req.user.id });
});

router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    req.log.info('submitted request at ' + Date.now());
});
```

You will now see `{ user : some_user_id, msg: 'submitted request at 01/03/15' }` in your logs which gives you the ability to tie any middleware in the request chain to a single user by using the `req.log` object.